# Can I drive a led light with help of a CT clamp

Tags: voltage, current, current-measurement, current-transformer

If I have a 230V wire with alternating current and a load in the far end, drawing current. Could you "steal" energy with a CT illustrated in the image, to for example drive a led light?

[image]

BR
Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is sometimes done in industrial situations to indicate the presence of current in a circuit. It's a bit of a waste to use a measuring grade CT for an indicator. If the CT is made with very thin wire and much less core then it will still be sufficient for powering an LED and may not need a series resistor.

It's typical to use a bipolar LED (the two-leaded LED package contains two dies of the same color connected back-to-back) so the LED conducts on both halves of the AC cycle. You could also use a bridge rectifier + LED or a put a diode across the LED and throw away the negative half cycle, or put two LEDs in inverse parallel. Here is a typical commercial product:

[image]

In this case, the maximum current through the core is 100A and it turns on at about 1-2A. By looping a wire through the core more than once, the range can be moved downward by reciprocal-of-integer factors. For example, three loops through would make the LED turn on at 0.3~0.7A (1/3) and allow a maximum current of about 33A in the wire.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing comes free so no, this isn't free energy that can be stolen. Somebody has to pay and if you use it in your household and you pay the bill then it's not stealing.

It will work but, the normal caveats apply when driving an uncontrollable current into an LED; some form of over voltage or over current protection is required.

Reverse voltage protection using a diode is also required or maybe usr back-to-back LEDs.